# breaking a loop at certain elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists, each with `[[product,rate,volume], [product,rate,volume], ...]`. Using the below framework, is there a way to break the loop once it has iterated through the products? So the loop stops before iterating through rate and volume?

```
for currentproduct, rate, volume in volumedifferencearray:
    for product, rates, volumes in cleanlist:
        if currentproduct == product:
            volumediff = volumes - volume
            volumedifference.append([currentproduct, rates, volumediff])
```

Comment: ```break``` keyword

Comment: set a condition and then use break as mentioned above

Comment: how would I set a condition that said "after iterating through currentproduct"? and then break

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the same products in both the lists (say list1 and list2) and want to have the volume difference in third list (say list3):

```
list1.sort() # sorts on first column, i.e., product
list2.sort() # same for clean list

list3 = [ [x[0],y[1],y[2]-2[2]] for x,y in zip(list1,list2) ]
```

`zip(list1, list2)` helps us iterate over both the lists at the same time.
`x` and `y` are corresponding elements `list1` and `list2`. Looking at the code in your question, my understanding is you want a list where first column is product, second column is rate (from cleanlist) and third column is the difference in volume.

So,

1. `x[0]` gives the product.
2. `y[1]` gives the rates from the clean list
3. `y[2]-x[2]` gives us the difference in volume

Example:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1]]
list2 = [[1, 4, 1], [2, 5, 0], [3, 6, 0]]

list3 = [[1, 4, 2], [2, 5, 0], [3, 6, 1]]
```

Hope this answers your question.